# Consider a symmetric positive definite $n \times n$ matrix $A$?How to show then entry $u_{kk}$ of $U$ has $u_{kk}=\frac{det(A_k)}{det(A_{k-1})}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Consider a symmetric positive definite $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with its $LU$ decomposition and $L$ has diagonal entries with all 1's. How to show then entry $u_{kk}$ of $U$ has $u_{kk}=\frac{det(A_k)}{det(A_{k-1})}$? ($A_k $ is a $k \times k$ matrix by taking the intersection of the first $k$ rows and $k$ columns of $A$). I appreciate some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Positive definiteness is irrelevant, so long as $A$ has an $LU$ decomposition.  Note that because $L$ is lower-triangular, $U$ is upper-triangular, and $LU = A$, we have $A_k = L_kU_k$.  Thus, $\det(A_k) = \det(L_k) \det(U_k)$.